# Kubernetes Cloud SQL sidecar connection timed out. How to check if credentials work?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to setup a Cloud SQL Proxy Docker image for PostgreSQL as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy).
I can get my app to connect to the proxy docker image but the proxy times out. I suspect it's my credentials or the port, so how do I debug and find out if it works?
This is what I have on my project

```
kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials --from-file=credentials.json=my-account-credentials.json
```

My deploy spec snippet:

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: mara ...
        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                    "-instances=<MY INSTANCE NAME>=tcp:5432",
                    "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

The logs of my cloudsql-proxy show a timeout:

```
2019/05/13 15:08:25 using credential file for authentication; email=646092572393-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
2019/05/13 15:08:25 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for <MY INSTANCE NAME>
2019/05/13 15:08:25 Ready for new connections
2019/05/13 15:10:48 New connection for "<MY INSTANCE NAME>"
2019/05/13 15:10:58 couldn't connect to <MY INSTANCE NAME>: dial tcp <MY PRIVATE IP>:3307: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

Questions:

- I specify 5432 as my port, but as you can see in the logs above,it's hitting 3307. Is that normal and if not, how do I specify 5432?
- How do I check if it is a problem with my credentials? My credentials file is from my service account `123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
  and the service account shown when I go to my cloud sql console is `p123-<somenumber>@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. They don't seem the same? Does that make a difference?

If I make the Cloud SQL instance available on a public IP, it works.

Comment: can you double check your instance connection name is correct? The instance connection name is available in the Cloud SQL Instance details page of the GCP Console or from the gcloud sql instances describe command. (from https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine)

Comment: @VasilyAngapov Hey! Yes, the instance connection name is the same as on the GCP console. What do you think of it trying to connect to port 3307 even though I ask it to be 5432? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I specify 5432 as my port, but as you can see in the logs above,it's
>   hitting 3307

The proxy listens locally on the port you specified (in this case `5432`), and connects to your Cloud SQL instance via port 3307. This is expected and normal.

> How do I check if it is a problem with my credentials?

The proxy returns an authorization error if the Cloud SQL instance doesn't exist, or if the service account doesn't have access. The connection timeout error means it failed to reach the Cloud SQL instance.

> My credentials file is from my service account 123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com and the service account shown when I go to my cloud sql console is p123-@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com. They don't seem the same?

One is just the name of the file, the other is the name of the service account itself. The name of the file doesn't have to match the name of the service account. You can check the name and IAM roles of a service account on the Service Account [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?_ga=2.78504593.-442290695.1543247497).

> 2019/05/13 15:10:58 couldn't connect to : dial tcp :3307: getsockopt: connection timed out

This error means that the proxy failed to establish a network connection to the instance (usually because a path from the current location doesn't exist). There are two common causes for this:

First, make sure there isn't a firewall or something blocking outbound connections on port 3307.

Second, since you are using Private IP, you need to make sure the resource you are running the proxy on meets the [networking requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#network_requirements).

Comment: That was an amazing dissection of the question. I'll go through your link. However, I'm having the same problem trying to connect from my laptop using `cloud_sql_proxy`. Does this mean the problem is on the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Are you trying to connect through Private IP? Your laptop won't be able to connect via VPC (it's not on the VPC and so it doesn't meet the networking requirements mentioned above.) If you want to connect to your Cloud SQL instance from an external network, then you need to use Public IP.

Comment: I realized that yesterday and just switched to Public IP. Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome post! I was facing a similar problem with "cannot connect timeout port 3307" and it turned out that my **Kubenetes cluster** was _not_ **configured to be vpc-native**

Comment: i am facing the same problem, cannot connect timeout port 3307 from sidecar pattern. from my spring boot application. Am using private IP. how to resolve it. it said in previous comment "Kubenetes cluster was not configured to be vpc-native" by @nover.. can you explain how to check that?

Comment: @Satscreate In the UI, you can click edit a cluster and search for "VPC-native traffic routing", which is under "Networking".

Comment: I'm having this problem but I'm not on a private address and also it's on the same VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy listen port 3307. This is mentioned on documentation

> Port 3307 is used by the Cloud SQL Auth proxy to connect to the Cloud SQL Auth proxy server. -- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy#troubleshooting

You may need to [create a firewall](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/add) like the following:

- Direction: Egress
- Action on match: Allow
- Destination filters : IP ranges `0.0.0.0/0`
- Protocols and ports : tcp:3307 & tcp:5432

Comment: This can't be the answer, it works just fine in a separate project with no firewall rule such as this.